# Is using an UITabBar as a menu in iOS a good option?

Tags: ios, menu

I am currently using a UIPopoverController to display my menu on the home screen.
I have the following options:

- Share button
- Go to View 2
- Go to About View

I'm planning to use a UITabBar instead of the Popover Controller.
Is it a good idea?

So far I've seen TabBar used only to navigate between 2 different views.
Is it a good idea to use it for a menu option (Share button)?

I will be using the TabBar only at the bottom and not in the other 2 views.

Comment: What are the UX differences between these two options?

Comment: @Erics In the first option, the user presses a button which reveals the menu in UIPopOver whereas in the second option, all the 3 options appear as buttons in the bottom tabbar. Is it allowed?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you shouldn't use the UITabBar in that way. The iOS 7 (and previous versions) uses the tab bar for backward navigation, and actions on current page. To navigate to another page, you should place link in content. Like this:

[image]

Repeat link is placed in content of the current event. If clicked, you go to the repeat option page, from where you can navigate backward to the event in the UITabBar. But as you see, there are no options to navigate to the retreat option from the UITabBar Controller from the event page.

Comment: So, I should use a button?

Comment: @BartSimpson Not really. A content link will be fine.